# Cómo puedo validar que se envien valores a dompdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

Muy buenos días, he tratado de validar que se envien los valores a mi pdf los cuales los envio a traves de una etiqueta

```
<a title="Boton Para Exportar PDF" class="btn btn-danger float-right p-2 m-2 w-25" target="_blank" href="../Layout/fichaPlanProgramaCarga.php?fechaEmisionPrograma=<?php echo $fechaEmisionPrograma?>">
```

y me salta este warning: Warning: Undefined variable $fechaEmisionPrograma in
C:\xampp\htdocs\views\JefWellboat\hPlanProgramaCarga.php on line 245.

el warning solo salta solo cuando se trata de exportar una tabla que no contiene datos, por ende he tratado de hacer una validacion para redirigir al usuario a la pestaña anterior si es que trata de exportar un pdf sin datos, pero no me ha funcionado:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../../model/database.php");

require_once '../../library/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

//Contenido HTml
ob_start();
$currentsite = getcwd();

$titulo ="INFORME DEL PLAN PROGRAMA DE CARGA";

if (!isset($_GET['fechaEmisionPrograma'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('AVISO: No hay datos para generar un PDF por favor verificar antes de Exportar un PDF.'); window.history.go(-1);</script>";
} else {
    $fechaEmisionPrograma = $_GET['fechaEmisionPrograma'];
}
?>
```

alguna sugerencia de como se podría manejar?

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué hay en la línea `245` del archivo `hPlanProgramaCarga.php`. Es probable que ahí intentes usar a `$fechaEmisionPrograma`, siendo que el código NO pasó por el `else` donde defines esa variable. Quizá deberías definir la variable como vacía fuera del bloque `if`.

Comment: Hola, @A.Cedano en la linea 245 tengo el redireccionamiento al pdf:                                                        <a title="Boton Para Exportar PDF" class="btn btn-danger float-right p-2 m-2 w-25" target="_blank" href="../Layout/fichaPlanProgramaCarga.php?fechaEmisionPrograma=<?php echo $fechaEmisionPrograma?>">

Comment: Voy a probar definiendola como vacia.

Comment: @A.Cedano, si funcionó pasandolo en vacio, pero aún así no salta la alerta y revisando el codigo en la linea 245 no importa si pasan los datos, sigue alertando, que la variable no se encuentra definida, debo tener mal desarrollado un query.

Comment: No entendí tu comentario: *si funcionó pasandolo en vacio* y *revisando el codigo en la linea 245 no importa si pasan los datos, sigue alertando, que la variable no se encuentra definida*. ¿Qué fue lo que funcionó entonces? No entiendo.

Comment: @A.Cedano mil disculpas, a la hora de pasarlo en vacio no me salta el warning y me redirecciona al pdf, pero aún tengo el error en la linea 245, que es donde se encuentra mi etiqueta para redireccionar al pdf, estoy viendo el error desde el navegador en el entorno de desarrollo.

Comment: Pero, ¿qué sigues viendo, **exactamente esto**: `Warning: Undefined variable $fechaEmisionPrograma in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\JefWellboat\hPlanProgramaCarga.php on line 245`? ¿Mismo mensaje, misma variable, misma línea `245`? Si agregaste la definición de `$fechaEmisionPrograma` **antes del `if`** es imposible que sigas viendo ese mismo mensaje, a no ser que el archivo viejo se haya quedado en caché y esté usando ese archivo viejo, en cuyo caso deberías limpiar la caché o usar el modo incógnito o llamar a la URL pasándole un dato sumplementario para forzar una recarga.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148811/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-diego-soto).

Comment: @A.Cedano si acabo de limpiar la cache, ahora probaré nuevamente

Comment: no quiero sonar duro pero ... **_que se envien los valores a mi pdf_** esto no es posible, saludos.